# How to make gradient border with mouse hover 360 degree rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```css
.clients-img::after {
 content: '';
 position: relative;
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2vyB.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
 transition: all 1.8s ease;
 width: 135px;
 height: 135px;
}
.clients-slider-inside img {
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 padding: 14px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 135px;
 height: 135px;
}
.clients-img:hover::after {
 transform: rotate(360deg) translate(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="clients-slider-inside">
<div class="clients-img">                                                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz2aw.png" alt="clients img">                                                    </div>
</div>
```

On Mouse hover rotate 360 degree and On Mouse out no any effect.
This type gradient border. So can you please help me for perfect rotation in circle.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service or "find this for me". Here we help you fixing smaller mistakes in your code, and that require you to make an attempt first at creating this.

Comment: Sorry but I tried with image and try to rotate but that not work fine.

Comment: Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader

Comment: @Hit Then you should include in your question, what you have tried. Show the code

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I edit my answer and add my code.

Comment: what's the issue ? i see that is rotating

Comment: @TemaniAfif But it is not rotate perfectly in around image and also it is move up and down when it is rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using an image and recreate the gradient using **multiple** `linear-gradient` on the background of the container. Then the idea is to rotate the whole container and rotate the image in the opposite direction so you create the effect of background rotation.

```css
.clients-img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(-15deg,#6fda44 25%, #fff 80%);
  transition:1s all;
}

.clients-img img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 135px;
  height: 135px;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition:1s all;
}

.clients-img:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.clients-img:hover img{
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="clients-img"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz2aw.png" alt="clients img"> </div>
```

Comment: @hi, ok so inside you mean ?

Comment: Please see my current code output in middle i need people image and outside on mouse hover rotate green border.

Comment: Please give left 0 and after that look green image is not rotate around image perfectly

Comment: why left:0 ? you want it to be like a border right ? i still didn't see the issue of the code ...

Comment: why left:0 ? you want it to be like a border right ? - Ans : Yes

Comment: @Hit and it's not a border right now ? no need to make left:0; as i sepcified width:100% ...

Comment: @Hit check again now ;) i improved the code to be a perfect border

Comment: Yes, Now it is good some modification need but i handle it, Thank you.